# Django post-form cannot validate when using Form with additional inputs

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form containing af `MultipleChoiceField` where the choices are created dynamic based on the given user

```py
class UpdateForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,names,*args,**kwargs):
        super(UpdateForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields["list_names"] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = zip(names,names),widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,label="Pick some names")

    add_new = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, label="Add new names?",required=False)
    delete_missing = forms.BooleanField(label = "Delete names?",required=False)
```

and it works fine as GET-request, the issues arrives with the post-request:

My view is the following:

```py
def update(request):
    user = request.user
    list_names = MyModel.objects.filter(user=user).all().values_list("nick_name",flat=True).distinct()
    form = UpdateWishlistForm(names =list_names)

    if request.method == "POST":
        post_form = UpdateForm(request.POST)    
        if post_form.is_valid():
            list_names = post_form.cleaned_data["list_names"] 
            add_new = post_form.cleaned_data["add_new"]
            delete_missing = post_form.cleaned_data["delete_missing"]

            messages.success(request, "Success")
            context = {
                "form":form,
            }

            redirect("home")
        else:
            #invalid post_form
            messages.error(request, "Error")
            context = {
                "form":form,
            }
            return render(request, "discounttracker/update.html")        
    else: #Get request
        context = {
            "form":form,
        }
        
    return render(request, "myapp/update.html",context=context)
```

The `post_form = UpdateForm(request.POST)` does not validate and the `post_form.errors` is empty.

It does contain data though (before calling `post_form.is_valid()`)

```py
print(post_form)
# UpdateForm: <UpdateForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(add_new;delete_missing;list_names)>

print(request.POST.dict())
#<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['...'], 'add_new': ['on'], 'list_names': ['test_name_1']}>
```

but I notice it is not bound, thus not validating. But I cannot understand why it's not "binding" when parsing `request.POST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the POST request, you need to pass the names as well, so:

```
list_names = MyModel.objects.filter(user=user).values_list("nick_name",flat=True).distinct()
form = UpdateWishlistForm(names=list_names)
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_form = UpdateForm(names=list_names, data=request.POST)
    # …
# …
```

But I would advise to work with a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) and thus pass a queryset. Since the nick names apparently can contain duplicates, it might be better to make a `Nickname` model, and use `ForeignKey`s to that model.

Comment: I have tried that aswell but that throws `__init__() got multiple values for argument 'names'`

Comment: @CutePoison: you likely used `UpdateForm(request.POST, names=list_names)`. Since `names` is the first parameter of your form constructor, that means that `request.POST` is seen as the value for the `names` parameter, and the second one as well, and this then raises an error, since there are two values for the same parameter.

Comment: Yup, I just figured that out that writing it as you did, made the difference - what is the difference between those two?

Comment: @CutePoison: see edit of the comment. It might have been batter to work with `def __init__(*args, names=None, **kwargs)`, and then construct this with `UpdateForm(request.POST, names=list_names)`.

Comment: @CutePoison In `UpdateForm(request.POST, names=list_names)` the `request.POST` is a positional argument and since in your definition the method signature has `names` first it is a value for that and immediately after you have a keyword arg for `names`.